# NETSUITE - Saved Search - Show employees are one year old today

Tags: netsuite

How to make and saved search to verify todays employee has exactly 1 year on company.

Example:

```
employee1 hiredate = 10/02/2015
employee2 hiredate = 11/02/2015
employee3 hiredate = 10/02/2012
employee4 hiredate = 10/02/2008
employee5 hiredate = 13/04/2008
```

Get saved search with all employee are 1 or more years old.

The result will be if today are 10/02/2016:

```
employee1 = 1 year on company.
employee3 = 4 year on company.
employee4 = 8 years on company.
```

Thats possible?

My wrong formula are:

```
MOD((ROUND({today},'DAY')-ROUND({hiredate},'DAY'))/365, 1) is 0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the same using the below formula(numeric) filter:

`MOD(MONTHS_BETWEEN({today}, {hiredate}),12)` is `equalto` 0

this will give you the employees having anniversary.

To get the number of years add the formula(numeric) search column with formula:

```
FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN({today}, {hiredate})/12)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not need a formula at all for this. You can just set up a filter on your saved search where the field is "Hire Date", the operator is "on or before", and the value is "same day last fiscal year". If you only want *exactly* one year ago, you can use "on" instead of "on or before".

If you want Employees that are more than 1 year but less than 2 years, then just add a second filter of "Hire Date - on or after - same day fiscal year before last".